# Optimal way to parse JSON-ish data- attribute like in Knockout.js, binding parameters format?

Tags: javascript, parsing

**TL;DR:** How to parse Knockout.js' binding parameters format (not JSON but similar)?

--

I have a question that I'm not able to answer myself.

I like the way Knockout.js and other MVVM libraries accept (understand) configuration in format

`data-bind="name: value, name2: {subname: subvalue, subname2: subvalue2}, name3: value3"`,

that is JSON-ish but *not valid JSON* (i.e. can get around nicely without the top-level `{}` or with parens).

The question is **how to parse this format** in the optimal manner, that is preferably using some built-in (shim) function and no eval, for example. Something like JSON.parse for example.

I've looked at the Knockout.js code to find the answer first, but I couldn't find the spot where the binding parameters are parsed. Maybe I'm overlooking the obvious, I don't know.

Suggestions or links or code or whatever sort of advice appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not just read the source of knockout.js? https://github.com/knockout/knockout

Comment: @mattmanser: As mentioned in the question, I've tried my best with that already but my javascript knowledge doesn't seem to suffice to find the parsing method.

Comment: Whoops! Scanned it too quickly. It looks like it's in here https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/expressionRewriting.js As you can see doing it well is hard!

Comment: @mattmanser wow that is terrible. I wonder why that approach was used, instead of a native way (e.g. JSON, JS object, etc.)

Comment: @mattmanser: Thank you, that's just it! If you paste it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. And, just as you say, it's hard. Much harder than I've expected :(

Comment: @Josua: I think they adopted this approach in order to minimise the character count and text complexity in the `data-bind` attributes. However in light of what the code looks like I think I'll go with standard JSON and native parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding source code for Knockout.js can be found here:

https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/expressionRewriting.js

As with all things parsing, the devil is in the detail, which is why it's so complicated!

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the source as mattmanser suggested (and he is RIGHT), the answer is in your question: Parse.

Specifically, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Edit: One way it could be handled is by reading the data-bind attribute as an array (effectively splitting on ','), and then parsing the items as name:value pairs. Again, without having looked at their source code.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. As mentioned in the question, the format I need to parse doesn't comply with JSON specification, or bluntly put, is not JSON. That means, unfortunately, that the JSON parser can't do the job in this case.

Comment: Just needs the opening / closing brackets. When you access the attribute from the DOM, add the opening / closing strings and then run the .parse().

Comment: That is exactly what I've tried at first, but at least in browsers at my hand no parser will accept the bare strings without parens. I know of the possibility to use valid JSON string, but at this point I would love to use the format as mentioned in the question.

Comment: That is clear. I'm no fan of eval and _no eval_ is mentioned in the question. Evil laugh is totally in place here :)